# Fixing " 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures." error for default props with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I have a function component `MyComponent` and I'm trying to set a default prop for `component` so that if not supplied, the root node will render as a "span". But I'm getting the following error:

```
TS2604: JSX element type 'Component' does not have any construct or call signatures.
```

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
  component?: React.ElementType<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>;
}

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<IMyComponentProps> = ({
  className,
  component: Component, <-- complaining
  ...other
}) => (
  <Component className={className}
    {...other}
  />
);

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  component: 'span'
};

MyComponent.displayName = 'MyComponent';

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 9):

My comment was incorrect. Try using `React.ComponentType` as the type for your input component.

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
  Component: React.ComponentType;
}

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<IMyComponentProps> = ({Component, ...other}) => {
  return (<Component {...other} />)
};
```

This would need to be used like so:

```
const Span = () => <span>Hey</span>

...

<MyComponent Component={Span}/>
```

However, this still leaves the issue of setting the default prop as a string.  You'd need to set the default prop to be a React component which returns a span. This is a higher order component and as such needs to have a React component as both input and output. If you want to just pass a single JSX element you'd have to type the input differently and not invoke your element prop as its own component:

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
  Component: JSX.Element;
}

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<IMyComponentProps> = ({Component, ...other}) => {
  return (<div>{Component}</div>)
};

...

<MyComponent Component={<span>Hey</span>}/>
```

**Maybe a better option:**

Use `createElement` to build an element dynamically from a string name, I can't think of another way to accomplish that.  This also gives you the option to pass a Class/Function component (though the example is only typed for FC's).

```
interface IMyComponentProps {
  Component: React.FunctionComponent | string;
  textContent: string;
}

const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<IMyComponentProps> = ({Component, children, textContent, ...other}) => {
  const newComp = React.createElement(Component,  { ...other }, textContent);

  return newComp;
};
```

Comment: I had previously tried using `JSX.Element` and `React.ReactNode` as types within my interface but changing it to `React.ComponentType` did the trick.